# #NeedHelp Apps script to send email when cell condition met in Google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am very new in code writing. I need help on this code that will send out an alert email when the cell value in column 9 = "Delayed"

```
function sendEmail(){

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet1 = sheet.getSheetByName('Adhoc Tasks');

var range = sheet1.getDataRange();
var row = range.getRow();
var col = range.getColumn();
var cellValue = sheet1.getActiveCell().getValue();

var taskDescription = sheet1.getRange(row,5).getValue();

if(col == 9 && cellValue == "Delayed"){

GMailApp.sendEmail("xxxx.xxxx@gmail.com", "This is Delayed Task Alert", "Hi there, this is to notify you that the " + taskDescription + "is DELAYED");
};
}
```

I've tried multiple ways but still unable to get the code to work.

Comment: How do you execute the function?

Comment: Do you realize that the row and col are for the upper left corner of getDataRange in sheet one which is probably 1 and 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my previous answer I assumed there was only one row of data.  Here is another example where there are several rows.

**Code.gs**

```
function sendEmail(){

  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let sheet1 = sheet.getSheetByName('Adhoc Tasks');

  let range = sheet1.getDataRange();
  let values = range.getValues();

  // assume the first row are headers
  values.shift(); // remove the first row

  // loop through all rows
  values.forEach( row => {
      let cellValue = row[8];
      if( cellValue === "Delayed" ) {
        let taskDescription = row[4];
        GMailApp.sendEmail("xxxx.xxxx@gmail.com", "This is Delayed Task Alert", "Hi there, this is to notify you that the " + taskDescription + "is DELAYED");
      }
    }
  );
}
```

**Reference**

- [Array.forEach()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_foreach.asp)

Comment: Hey thanks a lot. The code is working great now! You are the best!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example.  You don't say what row the values are is so I am assuming there is only one row of data.

**Code.gs**

```
function sendEmail(){

  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let sheet1 = sheet.getSheetByName('Adhoc Tasks');

  let range = sheet1.getDataRange();
  let values = range.getValues();

  // assuming there is only 1 row of data
  let cellValue = values[0][8];  // cell I1
  let taskDescription = values[0][4];  // cell E1

  if( cellValue === "Delayed"){
    GMailApp.sendEmail("xxxx.xxxx@gmail.com", "This is Delayed Task Alert", "Hi there, this is to notify you that the " + taskDescription + "is DELAYED");
  };
}
```

**Reference**

- [javascript Array](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp)

Comment: Hi there!
Thanks now the code is working. Its just there are actually multiple rows of data from cell I and E.
Any idea how i can work on that part? I will try to figure out from my end too.